# "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a little problem to deploy my container in k8 cluster in Google Cloud Platform.
Following I pasted a part of log error happened during step 17 ("RUN pecl install grpc") written on my Dockerfile, but I don't have any idea how to solve this issue, any suggestions?

> Step 17/52 : RUN pecl install grpc  ---> Running in 226d47d5eca8 downloading grpc-1.38.0.tgz ... Starting to download grpc-1.38.0.tgz
> (4,469,171 bytes)
> .............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done:
> 4,469,171 bytes 2052 source files,
> building running: phpize
> Configuring for: PHP Api Version: 20190902
> Zend Module Api No: 20190902
> Zend Extension Api No: 320190902
> ear/temp/grpc/third_party/upb -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/xxhash  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_ping.cc -o src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_ping.lo
> g++ -fvisibility=hidden -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM -D_GNU_SOURCE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -DNOMINMAX -DGRPC_ARES=0 -DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuseranMGkn/grpc-1.38.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuseranMGkn/grpc-1.38.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upb-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/php/ext/grpc -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/abseil-cpp -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/address_sorting/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/re2 -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/upb -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/xxhash -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11
> -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_ping.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/.libs/frame_ping.o
> ERROR
> ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 2

Thank you so much

Comment: Are you able to build your container outside Cloud Build? here it's an error in your container build process, that cause the error.

Comment: It's not possible to see the full trace error log, please could you share it ? Also it may be useful to check the official documentation on [Install gRPC for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc) , there are some required libraries before installing PECL which may be missing in your container , also there is a [similar issue on Github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21893) worth to have a look.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere if I build my Dockerfilein my docker Desktop (on Windows) and it works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating PHP library with Dockerized gRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585497/generating-php-library-with-dockerized-grpc)

Comment: @Pedro thanks for your reply but the situation on Google Kubernetes doens't change. The error is the same

Comment: @Pedro maybe I understand the problem. The failure is related to timeout fixed on 10min. Do you know how to increase this value for the workload deploy?